# How to draw a smooth simple line connecting a set of points?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, interpolation, curvature

Apologies in advance for the drawings, they are a bit wobbly.

Suppose you have two unique points in $R^2$. A straight line segment can be drawn between them. Say this line has the property "simple smooth".

Now, suppose you have three points, with a fixed start and end. A curve can be drawn through them, such that the curve is not squiggly, and the curve is continuous. Say this curve is also "simple smooth"

[Simple Smooth 3-point curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb5As.png)

To contrast, two straight lines connecting the points are not "simple smooth", because there is a sharp corner. Neither is two straight lines connected by a curved elbow, because this isn't as smooth as the first curve, since the curvature changes too drastically. Neither is a squiggly line, as seen in the picture, because it curves multiple ways.

[2 Lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3zVe.png)

[Curved Elbow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kase.png)

[Squiggly Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juP3l.png)

Consider if you have 5 points, where the start and end are the same, as shown below. You could draw an ellipse in this case, which would be considered "simple smooth".

[Ellipse, pretend it looks more round and less potato like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rKba.png).

Of course, some cases require "squiggles". Consider the set of 4 points below, with a fixed start and end point. In this example, an approximately sinusoidal curve would be considered "simple smooth", because there is no other curve to connect the 4 points that changes curvature less than that while being continuous.

[Sinusoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oylUR.png)

**Now for the general problem statement:**

Suppose you have a set of 2 or more points in $R^2$. One point is the start point, and the other is the end point. The start and end can be the same, all other points are unique. You must find a curve that is the most "simple smooth" that starts at the start and ends at the end point, passing through all other points at least once in any order.

Since it is difficult to express a general curve with this behaviour, the problem can be reduced to a simpler one: What is the expression for a quantity that represents the "simple smoothness" of a 2d curve?

My investigations so far:

Curvature seems promising, but I'm stuck on how to use this for quantifying simple smoothness, and also how to use it to minimize inflections.

Convexity and inflections were my first thought, but I don't know how to generalize that to be rotation-invariant in 2D (must treat x and y as interchangeable with no preferred direction or up and down)

Interpolation algorithms aren't good at dealing with non-function curves like circles, as far as I know. They also can change curvature or inflection quite drastically at times, creating "squiggly" lines.

Thanks for any help or ideas!

---

Comment: What about the condition “the set of curvatures is small” $i.e  Sup K - Inf K$, where $K$ is the set of curvatures, is as small as possible. Does this convey what you have in mind for simple smooth?

Comment: Maybe you can do something with [Bezier Curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! The $SupK−InfK$ formula seems to work for the examples I've come up with in the problem: squiggly lines like a sine wave have a larger range of curvatures in general than straight lines, ellipses and more simple smooth lines. It's possible there may be some edge cases that break the logic at some point, but it definitely gives a good starting point.

Bezier curves seem to have a lot of good properties, like symmetry and affine invariance, but it seems to approximate middle points instead of pass through them. Though, it may still be interesting to look into, thanks!

Comment: For three points, you can always place them on a circle, i.e., the circumcircle of the triangle. That is as simple as gets because the curvature is constant. My feeling is that with more points there are too many possibilities and it may not be possible to determine which is the *smoothest*. One possibility that you may not have considered is connecting the points with a spiral.

Comment: Once you decide on the order in which you visit the points, and for each point set a direction (i.e. tangent to the solution curve) then you can use a Bezier curve of degree 2 (or sometimes 3) between each pair of points which join together to form one smooth complete curve. Determining the order and the best directions may be tricky. Is the curve allowed to cross itself? If so, then you can have curvature as small as you like by going straight past a point and then using a really large turning circle to double back. This gives a path that looks like a flower with large petals.